# join table1 col1 alias to table2 col2 alias

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a way I can join on two tables like so:

```
.....
FROM table.col c
LEFT JOIN table1.col1 c1
ON c1.id = c2.id
LEFT JOIN table3.col2 c2 ON c1.id = c2.id
```

I tried this and does not work.

Wrote it wrong. Corrected main sql to show what I am trying to do. It says `c2.id` is not recognized in for this part `ON c1.id = c2.id`

Comment: You JOIN tables, not columns. I.e. `FROM table t JOIN table1 t1 ON ...`

Comment: wrote it wrong. Updated questions

Comment: @hnhl . . . I would suggest that you just delete this question and ask a new question.  Provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you are trying to do.  This question makes no sense.  The `FROM` clause defines *tables* not *columns*, so at the very least, `table1.col1` is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

For joining, you need to give table references, not column references.
The columns are part of the join *condition*.

See also the documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-join.html

According to your example for joining on 2 columns, you could do something like

```
SELECT ...
FROM table1
JOIN table2
  ON table1.col1 = table2.col1
  AND table2.col2 = table2.col2
```

Comment: @hnhl the question is still not ok... you've "LEFT JOIN table1.col1 c1" which describes the column 1 with an alias c1.... but you can't join directly on it.... you join on table1 THEN, you filter with c1 matching whatever you need